# How to implement Apple Sign In (Flutter) with a REST API backend (NET CORE)?

Tags: ios, flutter, rest, .net-core, apple-sign-in

I'm trying to implement SIGN IN WITH APPLE in my application (flutter app), and I've already managed to get the Authorization Code and Identity Token, but I got stuck on it and I don't know how to proceed anymore. I have to send these codes to my server and get user data from it, right? How do I proceed here, does anyone know?

When I implemented SIGN IN WITH GOOGLE, I got a token, sent it to my server, and calling an API I can get the user data, in the case of Facebook it was the same, but in the case of Apple, what do I do with these tokens?

Comment: I'm in similar situation, would be helpful to have insight. Most of the guides especially .NET covers web flow not for mobile

Comment: Did you ever find a solution for this issue?